# How to configure WSO2 ESB SAP Adapter

Tags: adapter, wso2-esb, sap-erp

I have already checked the information related to WSO2 ESB SAP Adapter from this link:

http://wso2.org/premium/summer-school-2011-session4-enterprise-integration-with-sap-and-wso2-esb

Is this the only information i can found about it?
I didn't find anything related to it in the official documentation of WSO2 ESB...
An example showing how to configure this adapter in the ESB will be very helpfull!

Thanks in advance,

Santiago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer following documentation for more info about WSO2 ESB integration with SAP.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Enterprise+Integration+with+SAP+and+WSO2+ESB

This documentation was added recently and I hope you will be able to find the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB comes with a variety of adapters to connect to all sorts of different systems. One of these adapters is the SAP adapter.

The WSO2 SAP adapter has full iDOC and experimental BAPI support. It used the SAP JCO library as underlying framework to communicate with SAP.

Installing the adapter couldn’t be easier. Its shipped with WSO2 ESB and the WSO2 ESB documentation website describes the installation procedure from the WSO2 perspective.

The installation procedure however does not guide you on how to find the settings you need in SAP.

That’s where this blogpost steps in. It is actually the first in a series of three. I’ll first take you through setting up the SAP connection. Then the next blogpost will introduce sending iDOCs and the last post will take you through invoking BAPIs at SAP.

So, let’s start off with some SAP adapter knowledge. I’ll refer to the WSO2 ESB SAP adapter as ‘SA’ in the following guide.

The SA is capable to be used as a Client as well as a Server. To setup the SA as client to a SAP system you’ll need to setup a client-side configuration fle. This file should be named [SAP-GWHOST].dest and must be placed in the [WSO2_HOME]/repository/conf/sap folder. This folder does not exist per default so make sure you create it and provide enough access rights for the WSO2 user to read the files within it.

To setup the WSO2 as an idoc server you must create a configuration file named [SAP-GWHOST].server.

Let’s first handle the client configuration file. There might be some differences based on your SAP system but the following settings should cover a lot of installations. The screenshots are based on SAP ECC version 6.0

In the examples [here](http://www.yenlo.com/en/configuring-wso2-sap-adapter/) the SAP gateway is known as SAPSYS01.

Comment: Please post the relevant content, link only answers are not good because links go stale.

Comment: There are many pictures in the blog, I have added the url for reference on how to actually configure the SAP adapter, would this do?